# API Authorization Strategy

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, authorization

I have a web application in node js that consumes an API for certain aspects of the content of the website e.g news.  The API is written in node.js and points to a mongodb database.

I would like some advice as to the best authorization strategy for this type of requirement.  I don't really need a user-name and password solution (I don't think).  Some sort of static token that the web app can pass to the API so that only applications that have this token can browse the data returned by the API.  I mainly want to stop just any old application consuming the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is best blog that can help you how to authenticate the REST Api in node js with the help of Basic HTTP Authentication, Oauth1 And Oauth2

*https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way*

*Basically there are the three type of authentication that generally used*

- Basic Authentication
- Oauth1.0a
- Oauth2

**Http Basic Authentication**

- More convenient, as you can easily expire or regenerate tokens
  without affecting the user's account password.
- If compromised, vulnerability limited to API, not the user's master
  account
- You can have multiple keys per account (e.g. users can have "test"
  and "production" keys side by side.)

**Oauth1**

OAuth 1.0 requires client to send two security tokens for each API call, and use both to generate the signature. It requires the protected resources endpoints have access to the client credentials in order to validate the request.

**Oauth2**

OAuth 2.0 signatures are not required for the actual API calls once the token has been generated. It has only one security token.

[Here](https://hueniverse.com/oauth/)  describes the difference between OAuth 1.0 and 2.0 and how both.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  
I would like to start with an API Key implementation as i don't require a username and password solution.  Can you advise which of the above best suits the below desired behavior? 

1. You get an API key from the service (shared secret).
2. Add the key to an Authorization header.
3. Call the API.